# accessing share from windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have a strange issue on one of our Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise machines. We have a one tree AD forest with a root domain and several child domains. In child domain A we have a share that is set up so that the users can access it from child domain B too. No problems so far, the users can access the share in child domain B on a machine that resides in the same domain.

Now we set up a new Windows 2008 R2 machine in child domain A. This machine is used by users from both domains A and B. The users from domain A can access the share, but the users from domain B can't. The error message states that the user doesn't have enough rights to access the share (while that is not correct, since the user can access the share happily from a machine in domain B).

I also have tried the user from a Windows 2003 machine in domain A and there the share is accessible for him. This lead me to the conclusion that something with that Windows 2008 R2 machine is not ok. I have switched off UAC and the firewall, but still no joy. Do you have any other ideas I could take a look into? Thanks!

Comment: What are the permissions on the share and what are the NTFS permissions on the shared directory? Do they include the users from Domain B in a universal group?